# how to merge dictionaries of lists with unique key values

Tags: python-3.x

I have below dictionaries of lists:

```
dict1 = {'SourceName': ['PUICUI'], 'EventType': ['XYX'], 'TableName': ['XYX__ct'], 'KeyIndex': ['XYX', 'ZXX']}
dict2 = {'SourceName': ['PUICI2'], 'EventType': ['XYX'], 'TableName': ['ZXX__ct1']}
```

And my below piece of code is working just as expected.

```
def combineDictList(*args):
    result = {}
    for dic in args:
        for key in (result.keys() | dic.keys()):
            if key in dic:
                result.setdefault(key, []).extend(dic[key])
    return result

print(combineDictList(dict1, dict2))
```

which gives me

```
{'TableName': ['XYX__ct', 'ZXX__ct1'], 'SourceName': ['PUICUI', 'PUICI2'], 'KeyIndex': ['XYX', 'ZXX'], 'EventType': ['XYX', 'XYX']}
```

But my question is how to print the final result to have unique values, e.g. here `EventType` has same values.
So, in final result i would only expect the final result to be

```
{'TableName': ['XYX__ct', 'ZXX__ct1'], 'SourceName': ['PUICUI', 'PUICI2'], 'KeyIndex': ['XYX', 'ZXX'], 'EventType': ['XYX']}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: Your values are in list. So you can store them as set, which will keep only the unique values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def combineDictList(*args):
    result = {}
    for dic in args:
        for key in (result.keys() | dic.keys()):
            if key in dic:
                result.setdefault(key, []).extend(dic[key])
                result[key] = list(set(result[key]))

    return result

print(combineDictList(dict1, dict2))
```

Comment: @change198 - if this solved your problem, then accept this as answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `set`

**Ex:**

```
dict1 = {'SourceName': ['PUICUI'], 'EventType': ['XYX'], 'TableName': ['XYX__ct'], 'KeyIndex': ['XYX', 'ZXX']}
dict2 = {'SourceName': ['PUICI2'], 'EventType': ['XYX'], 'TableName': ['ZXX__ct1']}


def combineDictList(*args):
    result = {}
    for dic in args:
        for k, v in dic.items():
            result.setdefault(k, set()).update(v)

    # If you need values as list
    # result = {k: list(v) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result

print(combineDictList(dict1, dict2))
```

**Output:**

```
{'EventType': {'XYX'},
 'KeyIndex': {'ZXX', 'XYX'},
 'SourceName': {'PUICI2', 'PUICUI'},
 'TableName': {'ZXX__ct1', 'XYX__ct'}}
```